# Protecting Laravel Root Directory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, permissions

I'm having a problem with denying access to the root directory of my Laravel Site...

I have my project in xampp/htdocs/laravel

Of course Laravel routes the /public directory...

But how can I deny access to the directory xampp/htdocs/laravel ...?
How can I prevent the directory listing?

The only way I've found is putting an index.php with a header("location: /laravel/public")

But I dont know if it's the best way... should I use .htaccess? How?
I've tried a few but it results in major errors across the server.

Comment: can you post your XAMPP config?

Comment: depends on how you've installed it.. how did you configure it so that incoming requests are routed to the Laravel `/public/` directory?

Comment: i simply installed xampp using the .exe for windows 7, then i run Composer inside my htdocs directory from the contextual menu (also installed composer from .exe) and run the commands to install Laravel

Comment: i mean,, i didnt do any config... whenever i do Route::get("something") Laravel is routing /public/something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open your httpd.conf file (xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf) and change the "DocumentRoot" value to include the path to your public folder:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just add a .htaccess with :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^ public [L]
```